# Identify currently-executing EC2 instance after --count > 1

Tags: amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

When firing up 5 instances from the command line thusly....

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-xxxxx \
         --count 5 \
         --instance-type m3.medium  \
         --key-name xxxxx \
        --security-groups xxxxx
```

Is there any way for each instance to identify itself distinctly from the enumerated list 1..5 ?  I do not want the instance id, I really want some sort of feedback from cloud-init to identify for any instance which of the five it is. Ubuntu 64 (non pv) if it helps. I am presuming ami-launch index ?

Comment: You will find what you are looking for here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

Comment: Thank you, yes. and externally the launch output tells me which is which. So I can run ec2metadata through grep and cut internally and export the resulting number (plus 1). There are limitations for a multi-machine launch in that the machines do not know their peers, or the total number actually launched without phoning home. They phone home in any case at the end of their work units for termination.  Cheers.

Comment: My observation also is that this does not work properly for spot instance launch groups. All of the instances return 0 for the ami-launch- index.
The user guide has some value, but there is a long way to go. I can still only launch spot instance requests with init data from a web page and not cli yet in any case.